# Apache mod_mime_magic add entry to detect mp4 file

Tags: apache

I have media files without extension but i cant server them using php as Apache needs `Addtype` directive which is based on file extensions but I cant use them so i have to let Apache auto detect mime types. I think mod_mime_magic can do that i have enabled it but it is not detecting mp4 files.

What values can i use in conf/magic file so Apache can detect mp4, flv, webm etc ? `MimeMagicFile conf/magic`

My conf/magic file has only these entries for media

```
# Quicktime video, from Linus Walleij <triad@df.lth.se>
# from Apple quicktime file format documentation.
4   string      moov        video/quicktime
4   string      mdat        video/quicktime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
4 string ftypmp4 video/mp4
```